# Conditional Drop Down Box with go to url button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up a page on my site that has *2 dropdown boxes*, with the second one being populated from the selected option in the first *dropdown box*.

My code works perfect, however I can't get the `go` button to find the selected value in the second drop down box to call the `URL` to go to.

How can I get the `Find Course` button to call the URL in the chosen option from dropdown box 2?

[Here's a demo of my code!](https://playcode.io/427491?tabs=script.js,preview)

Any help would be much appreciated :) I'm super new to JavaScript and advanced HTML.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="myQuestions">
        <select id="QuestionOptions">
            <option value="Aa">Choose a Faculty</option>
            <option value="Ba">Faculty 1</option>
            <option value="Ca">Faculty 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="myAnswers">
        <div id="Aa" style="display: Aa;">
            <div id="F1">
                <select id="F1answers">
                    <option value="A1">Course Selection</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Ba" style="display: none;">
            <div id="F2">
                                <select id="F2answers">
                    <option value="URL 1 GOES HERE">Course 1</option>
                    <option value="URL 2 GOES HERE">Course 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Ca" style="display: none;">
            <div id="F3">
                <select id="F3answers">
                    <option value="URL 3 GOES HERE">Course 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="FindCourse">
    <a id="CourseGo" href="HOMEPAGE URL"> Find Course </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#QuestionOptions').change(function () {
        $('#myAnswers > div').hide();
        $('#myAnswers').find('#' + $(this).val()).show();

});
});
var sel = document.getElementById('myAnswers');
sel.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("CourseGo").href = this.value;
}
```

Comment: https://playcode.io/427707?tabs=script.js,preview check this, 
maybe this will give you an idea.

Comment: document.getElementById('myAnswers') is a DIV and hold no value, you have to pick the value of one of your 3 pulldowns F1answers or F2answers or F3answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the [attribute id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) for multiple elements, however this script will work according your logic:

```js
const $myAnswersDiv = $("#myAnswers > div");
const $courseGo = $("#CourseGo");
const $myAnswers = $("#myAnswers");

$(function() {
  $("#QuestionOptions").change(function() {
    $myAnswersDiv.hide();
    $myAnswers.find("#" + $(this).val()).show();

    // targeting (#myAnswers > div > select) without style="display: none"
    let $selectVisible = $myAnswersDiv
      .not('[style$="display: none;"]')
      .find("select");

    // setting the current value of select to <a id="CourseGo">
    $courseGo.attr("href", $($selectVisible).val());

    // listener on the current <select> to set value to <a id="CourseGo">
    $selectVisible.change(function() {
      $courseGo.attr("href", $(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```